# How to get the claims within a JwtBearer-protected API method :)

Tags: api, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4, authorize-attribute

We currently have IdentityServer configured with JWT. We have about 8 API's each with 2-8 endpoints. Each of these endpoints uses the AuthorizeAttribute to verify if the user can use the endpoint etc..

This all works well but now we wish to implement multi-tenancy. Is there a way to use a token after an API has authorized?

Below is the basic flow

1. User click button on front end to initiate an API call
2. API endpoint verifies the access token with the identity server
3. User is allowed access if verified

It is after this stage that we wish to use the token again to query identity server for details on the user to allow us implement multi-tenancy

Have done numerous google searches etc.

The API code is as follows. Each API endpoint has the Authorize tag, which autorizes against the identity server to make sure the user can call the endpoint. Once the user is authorized, I need to pull data from the token to get the tenant

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("api/resultset/{userID}")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Get(int userID){
       //access token here to get details for multi-tenant
}
```

Comment: So you want your API endpoint to use the same token to call further APIs? It's just a matter of extracting the token out of the current HttpContext

Comment: You can use Policy-based authorization in API's. You need to check the user's claim whether is valid in there. For Policy-based authorization, reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: If you are talking about access aka bearer token, by default it's jwt, so it can be used many times until it expires. The only requirement to access UserInfo endpoint at IdentityServer is to have `openid` scope in the token -- you have to request it from the beginning. But for me it's hard to get how all above correlate with multitenancy. Usually tenant selection is one of the steps during user sign in, and after been selected, the tenant id is just one more claim within the token.

Comment: if the tenant claim is in the token, you do not need to parse it manually. when you write `AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer` in `ConfigureServices`, it extracts the claims for you so you can get them under `Identity` in the HttpContext.

Comment: Thanks guys for all your responses, Thanks @mackie

Answer (score 0):

After your call to API been successfully authorized, the claims from the token are under `HttpContext`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/resultset/{userID}")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Get(int userID){
    //access token here to get details for multi-tenant
    var claims = HttpContext.User.Claims;
}
```